# Public domain data for sample/training purposes

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I'm looking for some real-world data for use in creating database/educational training materials.

The sample should have a good [Entity-Relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) diagram/data model, multiple tables, and ideally SQL scripts with create tables/insert statements to run on my database (SQL Server ideally, but I'm flexible on that).